# How to from mysql query to sqlsrv query import to sql server database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

This is my code on mysql query that I want to change to sqlsrv query to import into sql server database

```
$message = null;

$allowed_extensions = array('csv');

$upload_path = '../csv';

if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {

  if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {

    // check extension
    $file = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $extension = array_pop($file);

    if (in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {

      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {

        if (($handle = fopen($upload_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], "r")) !== false) {

          $keys = array();
          $out = array();

          $insert = array();

          $line = 1;

          while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {

                foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                    if ($line === 1) {
                        $keys[$key] = $value;
                    } else {
                        $out[$line][$key] = $value;

                    }
                }

                $line++;

            }

            fclose($handle);    

            if (!empty($keys) && !empty($out)) {

                $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project', 'root', '');
                $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

                foreach($out as $key => $value) {

                    $sql  = "INSERT INTO `department` (`";
                    $sql .= implode("`, `", $keys);
                    $sql .= "`) VALUES (";
                    $sql .= implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($keys), "?"));
                    $sql .= ")";
                    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $statement->execute($value);

                }

                $message = '<span style="color:green">File has been uploaded successfully</span>';

            }   

        }

      }

    } else {
      $message = '<span style="color:red">Only .csv file format is allowed</span>';
    }

  } else {
    $message = '<span style="color:red">There was a problem with your file</span>';
  }
```

Comment: We are not a code translation service. You do the conversion, we'll maybe try help pick up the pieces after it blows up.

Comment: I know that is there any similar code for sqlsrv to import to the database

Comment: it's sql, using PDO as the library. you don't need to change anything except your DSN.

Comment: may I know is it instead of mysql change to sql?

Comment: You should use the differences of mysql query and mssql query so that can do the syntax level changes in query to execute on mssql server. Its not a big deal just do manually in your query.

Comment: may I have some example

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Janty I now changing to [department]

  $sql .= implode("`, `", $keys);
                    $sql .= "`) VALUES (";
                    $sql .= implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($keys), "?"));

may I know this how to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help you to do it manually.

Sometime MS SQL table or column names are enclosed in square brackets in queries (e.g. if contains spaces or for some other reasons). MySQL does not allow square brackets around table of column names, they all must be replaced by `symbol or cut off: [object] ->`object`.

So you need to remove all "'" from the table name department and its columns too in your above case.
For more.

http://www.convert-in.com/mssql-to-mysql-queries.htm

Added:

Your SQL Query will be as below. Please remove ? mark too.

```
                $sql  =   INSERT INTO department (;
                $sql .= implode(",", $keys);
                $sql .= ) VALUES (";
                $sql .= implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($keys), "?"));
                $sql .= ")";
                $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
                $statement->execute($value);
```

I am not well aware about PHP. I can only help to construct the SQL Query. Its should be

```
"INSERT INTO department (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,..) values(VALUE1,VALUE1,..)".
```

Added:

As I already told you I am not a PHP guy. But Tried for you. Please try your php code as :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO department (";
    $sql .= "implode(',', $keys)";
    $sql .= ") VALUES ("; 
    $sql .= "implode(',', array_fill(0, count($keys), ''))"; 
    $sql .= ")"; 
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql); $statement->execute($value);
```

But **array_fill(0, count($keys), '')** is empty data right?

Comment: You should do all such changes in the query to be executed on mssqlserver.

Comment: Can you please show me what exactly the query is constructed at runtime.

Comment: $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=name\SQLEXPRESS;dbname=project', 'sa', '');
         $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        
         foreach($out as $key => $value) {
         
        $sql  =   INSERT INTO department (;
       $sql .= implode(",", $keys);
       $sql .= ) VALUES (;
       $sql .= implode(", ", array_fill(0, count($keys), ""));
       $sql .= ")";
       $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
       $statement->execute($value);

Comment: yup @Janty I use this full code which appear above is alright for mysql but on sqlsrv it give a lot of error